# Return duplicate objects in array of large data using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Using JavaScript: I have an array of objects that I'm trying to determine the duplicate entries of so that I can eventually pass those duplicate entries to a separate function to remove them from a database.

My sample array could be:

```
const myArray = [
    { 'id': 111, 'lorem': 'ipsum' },
    { 'id': 222, 'lorem': 'dorem' },
    { 'id': 111, 'lorem': 'polus' },
    { 'id': 111, 'lorem': 'waifu' },
]
```

I'd want to return an array of all items that would be duplicate by the key `id`. In this example, my returned array would be:

```
[
    { 'id': 111, 'lorem': 'ipsum' },
    { 'id': 111, 'lorem': 'polus' },
    { 'id': 111, 'lorem': 'waifu' },
]
```

Most of the online tutorials have me iterating over a short list of data, and is great for such small data examples. But my dataset is in the thousands, if not millions, as my data grows. So I'm trying to find a smarter way of handling this logic.

I understand that I can run a `Set()`, but that doesn't actually give me the duplicate entries - *that gives me an array with non-duplicates*. My need is to return such duplicates, not to have a new array of non-duplicate entries.

Without using a third party such as lodash or underscore, how would I ideally iterate over an array with unknown size, to eventually return the duplicate items for me to pass up the stream for processing?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) - hint: don't do this on the client

Comment: Since your goal is to do changes in DB, do it directly in SQL rather than fetching the datas, transforming them in application, then updating the DB

Comment: I would do this https://jsfiddle.net/jr9f3yzw/

Comment: Check to see if an entry is in the Set; if so, then add to your array of duplicates.

Comment: @user1599011 Can you provide a solution with your Set logic please?

Comment: @Cid Very unfortunately I'm stuck with data in Firebase Firestore collection, so I have to manually iterate over and determine logic without a database.

Answer (score 0):

- Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), iterate over the array while updating a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to group items by `id`
- Using [`Map#values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values), get the list of grouped arrays
- Using [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), keep the arrays with more than one item
- Using [`Array#flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat), return all arrays in one list

```js
const myArray = [ { 'id': 111, 'lorem': 'ipsum' }, { 'id': 222, 'lorem': 'dorem' }, { 'id': 111, 'lorem': 'polus' }, { 'id': 111, 'lorem': 'waifu' } ];

const duplicates = 
  [...myArray.reduce((map, item) => // group items by id
    map.set(item.id, [...(map.get(item.id) || []), item])
  , new Map)
  .values()] // get grouped arrays
  .filter(list => list.length > 1) // keep duplicates
  .flat(); // return one array

console.log(duplicates);
```

Comment: My JS fails with the following error `Unexpected token '?'` at `[...(map.get(item[id) ?? [])`. Would you be able to dumb this down a bit for my node version or my linter or whatever is throwing this?

Comment: @ZachSmith try ``||`` instead as the nullish assignment is not supported in old versions

Answer (score 0):

This may take a while

I recommend you do this on the server

```js
// create an array with random IDs
const myArray = []
for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
  myArray.push({
    id: String(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)).padStart(3, "0"),
    "lorem": "ipsum"
  })
}

// examine them
const ids = []
const dupes = []
myArray.forEach(({id}) => {
  if (ids.includes(id)) dupes.push(id);
  else ids.push(id)
})
console.log(ids.length, dupes, dupes.length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment:

```js
const myArray = [
    { 'id': 111, 'lorem': 'ipsum' },
    { 'id': 222, 'lorem': 'dorem' },
    { 'id': 111, 'lorem': 'polus' },
    { 'id': 111, 'lorem': 'waifu' },
];
const uniqueItems = new Set();
const duplicates = [];
myArray.forEach(
  function(a) {
    if (uniqueItems.has(a.id)) {
      duplicates.push(a);
    }
    uniqueItems.add(a.id);
   }
);
console.log("duplicates",duplicates);
console.log("uniqueItems",uniqueItems);
```